# VirtualBox guest additions for Solaris

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, solaris

```
sudo pkg install VBoxSolarisAdditions.pkg
```

> ```
> pkg install: The following pattern(s) did not match any allowable packages.  Try using a different matching pattern, or refreshing publisher information:
> ```

```
sudo pkg install ./VBoxSolarisAdditions.pkg
```

> ```
> pkg install: Illegal FMRI './VBoxSolarisAdditions.pkg': Invalid Package Name: ./VBoxSolarisAdditions.pkg
> ```

```
sudo pkg set-publisher -p /media/VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.38_106717/
```

> ```
> pkg set-publisher: file protocol error: code: 22 reason: The path '/media/VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.38_106717' does not contain a valid package repository. Repository URL: 'file:///media/VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.38_106717'.
> ```

```
sudo pkg set-publisher -p /media/VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.38_106717/VBoxSolarisAdditions.pkg
```

> ```
> pkg set-publisher: file protocol error: code: 22 reason: Archive /media/VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.38_106717/VBoxSolarisAdditions.pkg is missing, unsupported, or corrupt. Repository URL: 'file:///media/VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.38_106717/VBoxSolarisAdditions.pkg'.
> ```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please include a listing of the directory containing the package.

Comment: execute this command `sudo pkgadd -d /full/path/to/VBoxSolarisAdditions.pkg`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the VirtualBox online manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idm2003):

> **4.2.3.1. Installing the Solaris Guest Additions**
>
> The VirtualBox Guest Additions for Solaris are provided on the same
>   ISO CD-ROM as the Additions for Windows and Linux described above.
>   They also come with an installation program guiding you through the
>   setup process.
>
> Installation involves the following steps:
>
> 1. Mount the VBoxGuestAdditions.iso file as your Solaris guest's virtual CD-ROM drive, exactly the same way as described for a Windows
>      guest in Section 4.2.1.1, “Installation”.
>
>    If in case the CD-ROM drive on the guest doesn't get mounted
>      (observed on some versions of Solaris 10), execute as root:
>
>    `svcadm restart volfs`
> 2. Change to the directory where your CD-ROM drive is mounted and execute as root:
>
>    `pkgadd -G -d ./VBoxSolarisAdditions.pkg`
> 3. Choose "1" and confirm installation of the Guest Additions package. After the installation is complete, re-login to X server on your guest
>      to activate the X11 Guest Additions.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I doing something wrong?

Yes. You are trying to use the Solaris 11 IPS new packaging command ([`pkg`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54763/pkg-1.html#REFMAN1pkg-1)) while VirtualBox guest additions package is built for both Solaris 11 and Solaris 10 so is using the legacy SVR4 packaging format and command [`pkgadd`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54764/pkgadd-1m.html) which is supported by both releases.